# Selenium Add-on/Extension in Chrome Browser

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

How to execute Add-on automatically in Chrome, Is there any shortcut key to execute.?

// In below lines i am adding .crx file and after that loading into chrome browser

chrome_options.add_extension("/path/.crx");

driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

So, What is happening after Add-on loaded we have to click plugin icon to activate and perform operation. But i need to activate without click into plugin icon.

Comment: Can you share your code attempts?

Comment: If you would of taken the time that it took to write this very un-detailed question, you would of found what you needed.  https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Always read the docs first!](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.html#selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.Options.add_extension)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

coptions = Options()
coptions.add_extension("path/to/extension/file.crx")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=coptions)
```